# Trying to get the width of a DropDownList in INT format

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, .net

I'm trying to get the width of a DropDownList, and it keeps coming over with the "px" at the end of it.  The final result I'm after is to determine the width of all the items in a DropDownList so I can set the width programatically.

Here's what I have:

```
    public static int FindTheWidth(object sender)
    {
        DropDownList senderComboBox2 = (DropDownList)sender;
        //            int width = senderComboBox.Width;

        var s = senderComboBox2.Width;
        var CBW = s.SubString(0, s.IndexOf("p"));
        int width2 = Convert.ToInt32(CBW);
        int vertScrollBarWidth = 2;

        int newWidth;
        foreach (string s in ((DropDownList)sender).Items)
        {
            newWidth = width2 + vertScrollBarWidth;
            if (width2 < newWidth)
            {
                width2 = newWidth;
            }
        }
        senderComboBox2.Width = width2;
        return width2;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The real width is available at the client only.

Comment: You want to use some Javascript/CSS for this at the client side, probably. Your server code has no idea what the presentation layer is doing (font size, etc, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The code has a lot of casting issues.

Type of `WebControl.Width.Value` should double.

Type of `((DropDownList)sender).Items` should be ListItemCollection.

```
public static int FindTheWidth(object sender)
{
    DropDownList senderComboBox2 = (DropDownList)sender;
    var width = senderComboBox2.Width;

    double doubleValue = width.Value;
    int width2 = (int)doubleValue;
    int vertScrollBarWidth = 2;

    int newWidth;
    foreach (ListItem s in ((DropDownList)sender).Items)
    {
        newWidth = width2 + vertScrollBarWidth;
        if (width2 < newWidth)
        {
            width2 = newWidth;
        }
    }
    senderComboBox2.Width = width2;
    return width2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The worst logic i have ever came across..Why to try presentation layer functionalities in bussiness layer,this is something like that...this is the desinging issue which you are trying to implement into server code? you can try setting width at the designing end.